# Why do I need Protractor when I have Cucumber and Selenium?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, cucumber, gherkin

We use Angular for front end development and Java for backend development. We use Cucumber and Selenium for BDD and end to end testing. I have recently read about Protractor and I came to know it can be used for end to end testing. But I am not understanding why do I need it when I already have Cucumber and Selenium. Can somebody please help me understand what is the use of Protractor when I already have Cucumber and Selenium? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Its just another wrapper around selenium webdriver (WebDriverJS) .Take a look at architecture .https://www.protractortest.org/#/infrastructure

Comment: Thank you. I read this before and I still don't understand why do I need Protractor when I have Cucumber and Selenium. Can Protractor do anything more than Cucumber and Selenium can do?

Comment: http://www.webdriverjs.com/protractor-vs-webdriverio-vs-nightwatch/ this article may help

Comment: Protractor is a wrapper of selenium by Javascript. Angular is code by Javascript.  Assume an app frontend and backend all are code by Javascript, i think choose a Javascript test tool rather than other languages like Java, Python is a better option. In your case, you had Selenium as test tool and Cucumber as test case framework.  You can continue to use them for end to end test.  If choose protractor,  you need code test case by Javascript.  Thus it's up to you to use Protractor with considering project members' tech stacks they currently hav,  is project urgency,  the investment/ return.

Comment: protractor is more specifically for web applications developed in AngularJS. You have cucumber and selenium to automate the angular application but it will not be synchronized with your web app and it will lead more maintenance than protractor. Protractor has its own customized methods to sync with angular app

Comment: Thank you all. Dev, what you mean by 'sync'? Could you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

### [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/)

[Cucumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber_(software)) supports behavior-driven development (BDD). It allows expected software behaviors to be specified in a logical language that customers can understand. Specifically, Cucumber allows the execution of feature documentation written in business-facing text. It runs automated **acceptance tests** written in a behavior-driven development (BDD) style. Cucumber BDD approach consists of its plain language parser called [gherkin](/questions/tagged/gherkin) that Cucumber uses to define test cases which is designed to be non-technical and human readable, and collectively describes use cases relating to a software system. The main purpose behind Gherkin's syntax is to promote behavior-driven development practice across an entire team comprising of developers, business analysts and managers. It firmly establishes the unambiguous requirements starting in the initial phases of requirements definition by business management and in other stages of the development lifecycle.

---

### [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor)

[Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) is an **end-to-end test framework** for [[image]angular](/questions/tagged/angular) and [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) applications. Protractor works with AngularJS versions greater than 1.0.6/1.1.4, and is compatible with Angular applications. Protractor in it's basic form is a Node.js program built on top of WebDriverJS. Protractor runs tests against your application running in a real browser, interacting with it as a user would. Protractor uses the [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) test framework for its testing interface.

---

### Conclusion

So the biggest difference seems to be scope of usage as *Cucumber* is mainly for the **acceptance tests** while *Protractor* is an **end-to-end test framework** specifically for the `angular` / `angularjs` based applications.

Comment: I appreciate everybody's answer. Dev was on the right track to answer my question. I would like him / her to answer my follow up question if s/he can. If anybody can give me an example of what Protractor is able to do that Cucumber cannot do, that would be a great help. I have Cucumber and Selenium already so I am trying to understand the use cases where Cucumber / Selenium combination alone cannot do all the tests. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor is tool just like Selenium, the difference between protractor and selenium is that protractor is better when you need to test Angular applications.

You can user Cucumber with Protractor also, just like you do with Selenium if you want to write your tests in BDD style.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber is a test runner that uses a BDD "Given, When, Then" approach to testing, allowing for descriptions and breakdowns of the tasks that make up a Scenario. You can wrap any form of test with these, and it increases the ability to communicate with the future dev/test team looking at a broken test, but also with the wider business.

Protractor is a library that allows for automation of websites, just like Selenium, with the key difference in their support for Angular.

Angular often loads in components after the page has already loaded, and Protractor will wait for these components to load without having to add in waits, which will end up speeding up your tests, or at least the writing of them.

Essentially, Protractor will make testing Angular easier out of the box, and there's no reason why you can't wrap Protractor with Cucumber if you want to take advantage of the communicative benefits of such a testing tool.